# Get Facebook page id from domain id or domain name?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using FQL Graph API i'm able to get the domain_id from a website using the following domain table query :

https://graph.facebook.com/?domain=www.facebook.com

which returns an output :

```
{
   "id": "369296215699",
   "name": "Facebook.com"
}
```

Now from this id I want to get the page which claimed this website. Page Name or Page Id anything of them will be able to assist me.

Comment: the id `369296215699` is assigned to the domain `Facebook.com` (in another way, that id is the Facebook domain object not the page), not to Facebook page on Facebook, what you're trying to achieve is not possible

Comment: I know that is the reason why i'm asking if there is any way by which I can get a page_id by using the domain_name or domain_id as there are pages on facebook which do have a completely different page name as compared to their domain_name.

Comment: that's not possible either, you're only chance is to use `/search` API and compare the domain with the results and decide which is the nearest to your query https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#types

Comment: @AdamAzad tried that to... thanks for your response but none of them helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching on google :

```
 domainname.com inurl:https://www.facebook.com/*/info
```

the first result is ur page!
Enjoy!

Comment: This can also be achieved (albeit, it's behind an App Review to access this endpoint) via the Page Search API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching/